# What library to include on Windows for stdlib.h functions?

Tags: c, windows, c-standard-library

I come from the Mac world, and am pretty new to Windows development. Very simply question: what libraries do I need to include in Visual Studio 2010 to get access to some basic functions like strtof() or snprintf()? Getting linker errors for these... `#including <stdlib.h>`, `<ctype.h>`, `<string.h>`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx

Comment: Both `strtof` and `snprintf` are C99 functions, and Visual Studio's C compiler doesn't support C99. There is an `_snprintf` function in `<stdio.h>`, which behaves differently from C99's `snprintf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSVC does not support C99, and only halfway supports the older versions of the C standard. `snprintf` and `strtof` were added in C99, and thus not available.

Comment: Only halfway supports older versions?  What parts of C89 doesn't it support?

Comment: Regarding C89, I seem to remember there being some preprocessor bugs, but I'm not sure right off. As for the later 94/95 amendments, try `wprintf(L"%s\n", "hello");` on MSVC...

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize there were amendments in 94/95, I just thought all of that stuff wasn't added until C99.  Sure, I can buy their not being compatible with those amendments, but AFAIK they're C89-conformant.

Comment: `wchar_t` and related functions were added, and MS botched them. :-) I think there may be some C89 conformance issues too, but probably not much worse than glibc's.